# How to send forcefully RST instead of FIN in android for tcp sockets

Tags: android, sockets, networking, tcp

So_linger does close the sockets but connection is closed normally , how can we send RST instead of FIN in android

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's almost always a really bad idea.

Comment: @EJP I'm curious, why send RST is a bad idea? Would you mind elaborate please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
socket.setLinger(true,0);
socket.close();
```

More info [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/net/articles/connection_release.html).

Comment: Thanks Peter , does java behavior apply for android too , would a RST be sent instead of FIN if we use the above statements

Comment: Yes I belive so. This sets the SocketOptions SO_LINGER: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/SocketOptions.html#SO_LINGER

Comment: @KC203 this isn't 'Java behaviour', it's how the underlying C Sockets API works, on any platform.